# Javascript get values to gridpanel

Tags: javascript, c#, extjs

I am trying to add values from my textboxes and combos as "history" to by GridPanel. The script looks ok, and my website should return my filled grid, but it doesn't happen.

```
    <script>

        var addRecord = function (form, grid) {
            if (!form.getForm().isValid()) {
                Ext.net.Notification.show({
                    iconCls: "icon-exclamation",
                    html: "Form is invalid",
                    title: "Error"
                });

                return false;
            }
            grid.store.insert(0, new MyModel(form.getForm().getFieldValues()));
            form.getForm().reset();
        };
    </script>





<ext:Store
        ID="Store1"
        runat="server"
        AutoSync="true"
        ShowWarningOnFailure="false">
        <Model>
            <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server" IDProperty="Id" Name="MyModel">
                <Fields>
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Id" Type="Int" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="A" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Operator1" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="B" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Operator2" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="C" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Wynik" />
                    <ext:ModelField Name="Data" />
                </Fields>
            </ext:Model>
        </Model>
    </ext:Store>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server">
            </ext:ResourceManager>

            <ext:Panel ID="UserForm" runat="server" Layout="HBoxLayout" Title="Kalkulator">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel6" Layout="VBoxLayout" runat="server">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Label ID="Label4" Margin="10" Text="A" runat="server">
                            </ext:Label>
                            <ext:TextField Name="A" Margin="10" MaskRe="[1-9]" ID="txtA" runat="server">
                            </ext:TextField>

                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel7" Layout="VBoxLayout" runat="server">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Label ID="Label1" Margin="10" Text="Operator" runat="server">
                            </ext:Label>
                            <ext:ComboBox Name="Operator1" Margin="10" ID="cbox1" runat="server"></ext:ComboBox>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>

                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel8" runat="server" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Label ID="Label5" Margin="10" Text="B" runat="server">
                            </ext:Label>
                            <ext:TextField Name="B" Margin="10" MaskRe="[1-9]" ID="txtB" runat="server">
                            </ext:TextField>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel9" runat="server" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Label ID="Label2" Margin="10" Text="Operator" runat="server">
                            </ext:Label>
                            <ext:ComboBox Name="Operator2" Margin="10" ID="cbox2" runat="server"></ext:ComboBox>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel10" runat="server" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Label ID="Label6" Margin="10" Text="C" runat="server">
                            </ext:Label>
                            <ext:TextField Name="C" Margin="10" MaskRe="[1-9]" ID="txtC" runat="server">
                            </ext:TextField>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel11" runat="server" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Button ID="btnhelp" Margin="6" OnDirectClick="helpclick" runat="server" Width="70" Text="=?">
                            </ext:Button>
                            <ext:Button ID="btneq" Margin="6" OnDirectClick="equalclick" runat="server" Width="70" Text="Oblicz">
                                <Listeners>
                                    <Click Handler="addRecord(#{UserForm}, #{GridPanel1});" />
                                </Listeners>
                            </ext:Button>

                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                    <ext:Panel ID="Panel12" runat="server" Layout="VBoxLayout">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Label ID="Label3" Margin="14" Text="Wynik" runat="server">
                            </ext:Label>
                            <ext:Label Name="Wynik" Margin="14" ID="lblsc" Text="Wynik" runat="server">
                            </ext:Label>

                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                </Items>
            </ext:Panel>
            <br />
            <ext:GridPanel
                ID="GridPanel1"
                runat="server"
                Title="Historia"
                Width="1100"
                Height="350">
                <ColumnModel>
                    <Columns>
                        <ext:Column ID="Column1" runat="server" Text="Lp" DataIndex="Lp" />
                        <ext:Column ID="Column2" runat="server" Text="A" DataIndex="A" />
                        <ext:Column ID="Column3" runat="server" Text="Operator" DataIndex="Operator1" />
                        <ext:Column ID="Column4" runat="server" Text="B" DataIndex="B" />
                        <ext:Column ID="Column5" runat="server" Text="Operator" DataIndex="Operator2" />
                        <ext:Column ID="Column6" runat="server" Text="C" DataIndex="C" />
                        <ext:Column ID="Column7" runat="server" Text="Wynik" DataIndex="Wynik" />
                        <ext:Column ID="Column8" runat="server" Text="Data" DataIndex="Data" />
                    </Columns>
                </ColumnModel>
            </ext:GridPanel>
```

When I click on button it doesn't work. What is an issue?

Comment: Could you reduce your code down to that which is causing the problem?

Comment: As I realized its all connected and I am not sure what part couses the problem. Mostly I think that the <script> section is somehow bad. Not sure

Comment: Try reducing the code down, bit by bit. Not only will it make it more likely that people will help, but it may also help you find the problem.

Comment: Problem is that the button at panel number 11 doesnt use the function on top

Comment: You haven't explained that in your question...